# How to compare elements within an array and store specific elements into a separate array?

Tags: java, arrays

I know similar questions have been asked. I've read through them and have developed what I thought was a reasonable solution to my problem. However, when I run the code it does not perform as I think it should. I'm obviously missing something here.

I need to read in a string (a propositional logic statement) and determine how many variables it has. My thought process is: convert the string to a `charArray` and compare the elements. If a certain element is a letter AND is not equal to another element in the array, it is a new variable, thus adding to the variable count, and also needs to be stored in a separate array for later use.

```
public class PropLogic {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    String statement;
    int numOfVariables = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter your propositional statement:");
    statement = stdin.nextLine();
    char[] charStatement = statement.toCharArray();
    char[] variables;
    variables = new char[25];

// Counts number of variables in statement
   for (int i = 0; i < statement.length(); i++){
       for(int j = i + 1; j < statement.length(); j++){
           if(Character.isLetter(charStatement[i]) && (charStatement[i] != 
charStatement[j])){
               variables[i] = charStatement[i];
               numOfVariables++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number of variables is " + numOfVariables);
    System.out.println("The variables are " + new String(variables));
}}
```

With input "hello" I get output of 9 variables and that the variables are "hell" when I want to be getting 4 variables that are "hello".

Comment: from a quick read, looks like you need some form of lexical and syntactical analysis instead, it'll perform better for reading the whole propositional logic statement

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a `Set`.  A set has the property that you can enter the same object only once into it.  Here is one version:

```
    Set<Character> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for(int i = 0; i< statement.length(); i++) {
        set.add(statement.charAt(i));
    }

    System.out.println("The number of variables is " + set.size());
    System.out.println("The variables are ");
    set.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: So does a set prohibit the user from inputting multiple of the same objects? If so that won't work because a propositional statement can have multiple instances of the same variable (ex. (p ^ q) V p)

Comment: Adding a repeat object to a Set simply does nothing; it is not prohibited :-)

Comment: @adc395, I have to ask out of curiosity since this is not my area but if you add your example you will have [(p^q)V], don't you need that second p to understand the statement properly?

Comment: So thus far, my knowledge only extends (barely) to arrays, and I'm pretty uncertain about how sets work. I will do some research on this and try to implement it best I can, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

*Problem 1.* Think about what happens, for example, with the "h" of "hello." You compare it, in turn, to "e", "l", "l", and "o", and *for each of them*, you add a new variable. What you want is to add a new variable *only if* ALL of the future letters are not equal to the "h." This is why you are getting 9 variables total: you add one for each of the following comparisons:

```
(h, e), (h, l), (h, l), (h, o)
(e, l), (e, l), (e, o)
(l, o)
(l, o)
```

This is also why you are getting "hell" as your final variables array. The `o` is never compared to anything, so never gets added to the array.

What you really want to do is go through the entire rest of the string, and check if anything is equal to the current letter. You can do this with a boolean flag. Here is pseudocode:

```
for i = 0 to len(charArray):
   isNewVariable = isLetter(charArray[i])
   for j = i+1 to len(charArray):
     if charArray[i] == charArray[j]:
        isNewVariable = false
   if isNewVariable:
     Add charArray[i] to variables
```

*Problem 2.* You are filling in the wrong index of your variables array. You want to fill in `variables[numOfVariables]`, not `variables[i]`. Let's say the first and seventh letters are variables; then you want `variables[0]` and `variables[1]` to be set to the two variables, *not* `variables[0]` and `variables[6]`, which is what your current code does.

Hope this helps! If you fix these two errors, your code will work; however, as other answers point out, this general strategy is not the best for this specific task. Incrementally adding to an array (like `variables`) is best done with an `ArrayList`; even better, a `Set` is exactly suited for the task of finding just the unique elements of an array.

Comment: Thank you Alex, this really helped me understand why I was getting 9 variables. I'm inclined to stay with the array approach for now (even if its not the most efficient) because I don't know about sets yet and my time is limited on this problem. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use char array since String has the methods `CharAt()` and `contains()`.

Then you have to run through your String. When you find a new letter (which mean this letter is not in the already found array), you put it in the already found array and you increment your counter. (note that the counter is useless since it as the same value as the length of the already found array). You should obtain something like this :

```
String statement = stdin.nextLine();
String variables = ""; //empty String

//Go through the whole String statement
for (int i = 0; i < statement.length(); i++){
    //Check if this letter was not already found and it's a letter
    if(!variables.contains(statement.charAt(i)) && Character.isLetter(statement.charAt(i)) ){
         //Add this letter to the found ones
         variables.concat(String.valueOf(statement.charAt(i)));
    }
}
System.out.println("The number of variables is " + variables.length());
System.out.println("The variables are " + variables);
```

Answer (score 0):

what is happening here is, check if char exists in temp string with `'temp.indexOf(char)'`, it returns 1 if it exists at an index of that string and 0 otherwise.
so if 0, then add and loop to next char.

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    String statement;
    int numOfVariables = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter your propositional statement:");
    statement = stdin.nextLine();
    char[] charStatement = statement.toCharArray();
    char[] variables;
    variables = new char[25];

    String temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < statement.length(); i++){
        char current = statement.charAt(i);
        if (temp.indexOf(current) < 0){
            temp = temp + current;
        } 
    }

    System.out.println("The number of variables is " + temp.length());
    System.out.println("The variables are " + temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with not insisting on `char[]` variables and use `List<Character>` instead, this does the job

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PropLogic {

    public static List<Character> parseVariables(char[] input) {
        List<Character> candidates = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
            Character c  = input[i];
            if( Character.isLetter(c) && !candidates.contains(c)) {
                candidates.add(c);
            }
        }

        return candidates;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Enter your propositional statement:");
        char[] charStatement = stdin.nextLine().toCharArray();

        List<Character> variables =  parseVariables(charStatement);

        System.out.println("The number of variables is " + variables.size());
        System.out.println("The variables are " + variables);
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
   Enter your propositional statement:
   hello1
   The number of variables is 4
   The variables are [h, e, l, o]
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful. If I only wanted to add a variable to the list if it was a letter, how would I go about checking if it was a letter? Can I use isLetter() in this situation? Sorry for my confusion, I'm still trying to just get a grip on the syntax/rules as well

Comment: Yes, amended the example.

Answer (score 0):

A key to success in writing good programs is to make sure it has as few lines of code as possible and it doesn't repeat an operation that it has already performed or that is not even needed.

If you think about your problem statement, basically, all you need to do is extract letters from a given input string and remove duplicates. With advance programming languages like Java, String operations shouldn't take more than a couple of lines of codes. If it is more than 2 lines, in most cases, it has a lot of boiler plate code.

See if the following line of code meets your objective.

`Set<String> variables = Arrays.stream(statement.split("")).filter(str -> Character.isLetter(str.charAt(0))).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I was completely unaware of Sets as my knowledge to date only extends (barely) to arrays

Comment: @adc395, arrays in Java, although considered objects, don't offer useful methods. Always use List or Set as they offer lots of useful methods which make your program succinct.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 1-liner:

```
String[] variables = statement.replaceAll("[^a-z]|(.)(?=.*\\1)", "").split("(?<=.)");
```

This uses regex to remove (by replacing with a blank) all non-lowercase letters OR all letters that are repeated later on (ie remove dupes).

Then it splits after each letter giving you the final array of unique letters from the input.

Note that this creates a `String[]` rather than a `char[]`, which you can just as easily use. If you really want a `char[]`, you can do this:

```
String[] variables = statement.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").chars()
    .distinct().mapToObject(c -> (char)c).toArray();
```